installing pycoral results in "unmet dependencies" error despite dependencies being met
I'm getting the following error when installing pycoral via sudo apt-get install python-pycoral on my Chromebook
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pycoral : Depends: python3-tflite-runtime (= 2.5.0.post1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I confirmed that my set up meets the listed requirements, however the pycoral installer seems to be ignoring tflite -- which appears in pip list -- as well as the current python version.
If you have experience with this I'd appreciate any help getting around it. From the weirdness of the "unmet dependencies" error I have a feeling there's a problem with something(s) outside of the tflite runtime and python version
